# Why does this JavaScript cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript

The following code is regarded as causing a memory leak because `element` maintains a reference to function `bar` and `bar` maintains a reference to `element` via closure (if I understand correctly).

Why does this cause a memory leak? Does it only cause a leak when `element` is a DOM node?

```
function foo(element, a, b) {
  element.onclick = function bar() { /* uses a and b */ };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code only caused a memory leak in certain old versions of Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer 8 made some changes to memory management which mitigated the problem:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361842(v=vs.85).aspx

As all of the affected versions of Internet Explorer are now thoroughly obsolete, this is no longer an issue you need to be concerned with.

Comment: So this category of problem (the creation of circular object references) is no longer an issue? I presume by garbage collectors being able to detect "islands" of object-graph?

Comment: more info about "circular object references" can be found here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks

Comment: @BenAston Correct. Technology has moved forward; modern JS runtimes can detect and collect circular references.

Comment: @duskwuff Given this, can you show me how to create a memory leak in JS on a modern browser?

Comment: @BenAston Not reliably. Any memory leak in a modern web browser is a bug, and should be reported to the appropriate developers to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a Javascript closure and is an expected feature of Javascript.  This is not a memory leak in any modern browser.

If the DOM element represented by `element` is removed from the DOM, then the onclick handler will be garbage collected and then the closure itself will be garbage collected.

During the lifetime of `element`, the variables `a` and `b` will be part of the closure.  This is an expected language feature as they are part of the closure that this code creates.  When and if, `element` is deleted from the DOM and it is garbage collected, the closure and its references `a` and `b` will be eligible for garbage collection too.

There are some old browsers that did not always handle this properly, but that is generally not considered a design consideration any more for modern browsers.  Further, it only caused an issue of consequence if you ran code like this over and over (removing DOM elements each time too) such that a large enough amount of memory was consumed by things that weren't being garbage collected when they should have been.  This typically only happened in long running single page applications that had a lot of dynamic DOM stuff going on.  But, as I said with modern browsers, this is no longer an issue as the browser's garbage collector handles this situation now.

Comment: I was told that both nulling the element variable (`var elem = document.getElementById('id'); elem.onclick = function() { /* ... */ }; elem=null;`) OR not using a variable for the element (`document.getElementById('id').onclick = function() { /* ... */ };`) would fix the `IE<8` memory leak. Were both a valid way to break that DOM to handler memory leak?

Comment: @GitaarLAB - are you seriously trying to deal with memory leaks in versions of IE before IE 8?  Not creating a closure in the first place is probably the best way to avoid this type of issue in ancient browsers.  Generally not considered something one should spend development time on now.

Comment: Yep. But its also interesting matter. And I happen to maintain some legacy stuff that uses embedded IE controls. I also maintain some stuff were backwards compatibility is required. But in the end.. information never hurted anyone (like a future visitor who wondered how they solved the problem 'back then')..